How to enable the history of the terminal in VS Code
I don't know how I enabled this feature before, but I found it incredibly useful for someone who primarily works in the terminal.
It displays the history of commands based on my inputs, allowing me to select them quickly. Now, I have no way to enable this table again... I've already searched on Google for this feature, but I don't see anyone mentioning it...


This isn't a feature of the "vscode terminal" but of the actual terminal application. VSCode just hosts your favorite terminal, be it pwsh, bash, zsh etc. So you probably had a plugin for that (or even a different terminal).

The screenshot looks like Oh My Posh with PSReadLine installed. You can configure the history and autocompletion in your PowerShell profile (type $profile to show the path, or directly open it with code $profile if you have e.g. VSCode in your $PATH):
Import-Module PSReadLine
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView


Awesome, I can enable it now. I'm still unsure how I got it enabled before, but it helps me a lot. Thanks for your help.

using this command in terminal can show you the history of commands
history

maybe you can find the whole history in your .zsh_history or .bash_history?
if you can't display the history of commands by using this command,you may need reset the bash config file.
like  ~/.zshrc includes
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=2000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history

reload file：
source ~/.zshrc


The history command can display the history, but what I am asking for is something that interacts with each character I input.
From the captured image, you can see that I am typing helm and the history table is just showing all the commands I've entered that start with helm... before, allowing me to easily select which command I want to use.
